# Change Product price daily

Tags: magento-1.9, price, cron

One of My client has requirement to change product price daily 
ie- he fill the product price for all month at once when month start 
eg- day1:$10, day2:$15, day3:$12, day4:$11 and so on to last date
my idea is create 31 products attributes to fill price & run a cron job daily to set product price according to date like if date is 1st set price of attribute day1 & if date is 2nd set price of attribute day2 & so on 
but I didn't have any idea about how to run cron job as per my requirement , can anyone guide me how to use cron job as per requirement or any other best idea to fulfil the above requirement

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: do you have specific rules for how the price will change or is ist just arbitrarily

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the prices are random and impossible to figure out a formula, you could either create 31 product attributes (ie today_price_1...31) for each day, create one attributes and enter the price for each day as a csv or create a csv upload that keep track of the product id/sku and each day price for all the item that need to be updated.

Assuming that there is a formula, then you will need to figure out if this formula should apply to the current day price or the original base product price. You may want to consider using/changing the "special price" so you can all way know what the base price is (assuming it always more)

Module

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <pricecron>
                <class>MagePal_PriceCron_Model</class>
            </pricecron>                            
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <pricecron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>pricecron/observer::setPrice</model>
                </run>
            </pricecron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

In `app/code/local/Roomstory/Invoice/Model/Observer.php` add the following:

```
<?php
class MagePal_PriceCron_Model_Observer {
    public function setPrice() {
        //to do - get today day index (assuming 1)
        $todayIndex = 1;

        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        //Assuming you are using product attributes
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach($products as $product) {
            //get attribute base of today
            $todayPrice = $product->getData('today_price_' . $todayIndex);
            if($todayPrice > 0){
                //may want to think about using special price
                $product->getPrice($todayPrice);
                $product->save();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help ,let me one thing where to put config code in app/code/local/Roomstory/config.xml right

Comment: is  I need to create new module named Roomstory